# Firebase multiple app flavors same google-services.json file onTokenRefresh() not called

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an application having multiple product flavors sharing the same google-services.json file.
My problem is I have checked everything and my implementation is right but I am not able to get the callback for this class in my app

```
public class FirebaseTokenRegister extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Log.d("TAG", "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("phoenix");
    Logger.d(FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken());
    Toast.makeText(Base.getContext(), refreshedToken, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

I have set this class in manifest also

```
    <service android:name=".model.firebase.FirebaseTokenRegister"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service android:name=".model.firebase.FireBaseMessageNotify"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

I have checked everything again and again but the method `onTokenRefresh()` 
is not called anyhow. I have tried installing and uninstalling the app.
Now i am having a doubt that wether it's the right way to implement the product flavors sharing the same google-services.json file?

Please help

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceIdService

Comment: Sir i am using older version of it so it should work now it's working.

Comment: it probably makes little sense to fix something which had been replaced already.

Answer (score 1):

The error was I was having

```
 <application
    android:name=".AppController"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="${appIcon}"
    node="replace"
    android:label="${flavored_app_name}"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

This was causing problems in manifest merging so this was resolved after changing.